# Javascript: objects and functions ... Can someone explain why this wont work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying out a code and it won't seem to work.
Can someone tell me what I'm missing here, thanks in advance!

javascript

```
var entity = function (type, w, h, c, kickSpeed, accuracy, power) {
    var entity = {};
    entity.type = type;
    entity.appearance = {
        w : w,
        h : h,
        c : c
    };
    entity.attribute = {
        kickSpeed : kickSpeed,
        accuracy : accuracy,
        power : power
    };
    return entity;
};

var spawnPlayer = function () {
    var player = {};
    entity("player", 50, 50, "green", 10, 1, 10);
    entity = player;
    ctx.fillRect(1, 1, player.appearance.w, player.appearance.h);
};
spawnPlayer();
```

The problem in this code is it cant find the player.appearance object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the entity function that is returning the value to the player variable so it is never defined. You should read up on [variable scopes](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/).

```
var entity = function (type, w, h, c, kickSpeed, accuracy, power) {
    var entity = {};
    entity.type = type;
    entity.appearance = {
        w : w,
        h : h,
        c : c
    };
    entity.attribute = {
        kickSpeed : kickSpeed,
        accuracy : accuracy,
        power : power
    };
    return entity;
};

var spawnPlayer = function () {
    var player = entity("player", 50, 50, "green", 10, 1, 10);
    ctx.fillRect(1, 1, player.appearance.w, player.appearance.h);
};
spawnPlayer();
```

Here is the JSfiddle, with an alert to show its working.

https://jsfiddle.net/5u8bvst0/

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to assign the entitiy.

`player = entity("player", 50, 50, "green", 10, 1, 10);`

Answer (score 1):

Just put this line

```
var player = entity("player", 50, 50, "green", 10, 1, 10);
```

and remover

```
entity=player
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are not assigning anything to the player object

```
var spawnPlayer = function () {
  // here you define a new variable
  var player = {};
  // then you execute the function but the result are gone
  entity("player", 50, 50, "green", 10, 1, 10);
  // at the end you destroy the function definition assigning an empty object to it
  entity = player;
  ...
};
```

Instead you should:

```
var spawnPlayer = function () {
  //execute the entity and assign to player
  var player = entity("player", 50, 50, "green", 10, 1, 10);
  //do whatever
};
```